# A way to export the results from Pig to a database

Tags: database, export, hadoop, apache-pig

Is there a way to export the results from Pig directly to a database like mysql?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While keeping in mind what orangeoctopus said (beware of DDOS...) have you had a look to [DBStorage](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/branches/branch-0.8/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/DBStorage.java?view=markup)?

```
data = LOAD '...' AS (...);
...
STORE data INTO DBStorage('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', 'dbc:mysql://host/db', 'INSERT ...');
```

Answer (score 4):

The main problem I see is that each reducer is effectively going to insert into the database around the same time.

If you don't think this will be an issue, I suggest you write a [custom Storage method](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/udf.html#Store+Functions) that uses JDBC (or something similar) to insert into the database directly and writing nothing out to HDFS.

If you are afraid of performing a DDOS attack on your own database, perhaps collecting the data on HDFS and performing a separate bulk load into mysql would be better.

Comment: Seems like there is no way around writing a UDF that uses JDBC..thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently experimenting with an embedded pig application which loads results into mysql via [PigServer.OpenIterator](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/api/org/apache/pig/PigServer.html#openIterator%28java.lang.String%29) and a JDBC connection.  It's worked very well in testing, but I haven't tried it at scale yet.  This is similar to the custom storage method already suggested, but runs from a single point, so no accidental DDOS attack.  You effectively end up paying the network transfer cost twice (cluster -> staging machine, staging machine -> DB server) if you don't run the load off the DB server (I personally prefer to run nothing except the DB itself off the DB server), but that's no different than the "write the file out and bulk load it" option.

Answer (score 2):

Sqoop may be the good way to go, but it is difficult to set-up (IMHO) as all these Hadoop related projects...

Pig's DBStorage is working fine (at least for storing).

Don't forget to register the PiggyBank and your MySQL driver:

```
-- Register Piggy bank
REGISTER /opt/cmr/pig/pig-0.10.0/lib/piggybank.jar;

-- Register MySQL driver
REGISTER /opt/cmr/mysql/drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar
```

Here is a sample call:

```
-- Store a relation into a SQL table
STORE relation INTO 'unused' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.DBStorage('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', 'jdbc:mysql://<mysqlserver>/<database>', '<login>', '<password>', 'REPLACE INTO <table> (<column1>, <column2>) VALUES (?, ?)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Sqoop](https://github.com/cloudera/sqoop/wiki/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.