# Store the results from Pig directly to Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-pig, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to store the results from Pig directly to a table on Redshift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you won't like it probably - it's not efficient.

1. Download jdbc driver (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html)
2. Use PiggyBank DBStorage, mysql example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12977447/4368212).

A better way is to prepare csv and then import it.